# Flexbe App fails to process custom state

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to flexbe and am having trouble adding my own state using the app gui.
I am launching the App using the following command

```
roslaunch flexbe_app flexbe_full.launch
```

The app launches successfully. When I go to the Configuration tab and show the terminal it shows the error

```
[State parser] Failed to process nht_flexbe_states.get_pose (name 'frame_map' is not defined)
```

Where the get_pose.py contains the following snipper

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf

from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped

from flexbe_core import EventState, Logger
class GetAgentPose(EventState):
    '''
    get position of agent in map frame

    -- frame_map  string       name of the map tf frame

    -- frame_agent  string        name of fixed robot base frame

    #> pose_agent   PoseStamped current location of mobile agent in map frame

    <= done                      calculated transform

    <= failed                   Failed to calculate transform

    '''

    def __init__(self, frame_map, frame_agent):
    
        super(GetAgentPose, self).__init__(outcomes = ['done', 'failed'],
                                            output_keys = ['pose_agent'])

        self.target_frame = frame_map
        self.source_frame = frame_agent
```

I've noticed that the name in the error changes to reflect the variable I have in the line `self.target_frame = frame_map` (and not in the **init** or the docstring). I used the tutorial to create the containing package, and the ExampleState appears as a viable option in the Statemachine editor. The issue persists after running catkin_make and restarting the app.

I'm running melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.4 with Flexbe 2.2.4

I've also noticed the following error in the terminal echo when starting the app, but I'm uncertain if it is related.

```
[10371:10371:0623/164650.772048:ERROR:component_loader.cc(165)] Failed to parse extension manifest.
(node:10411) [DEP0025] DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
```

Any pointer on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355675/flexbe-app-fails-to-process-custom-state/) by [chives_onion](https://answers.ros.org/users/39292/chives_onion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2020-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I had the simple mistake of mixing tab and space indentation. I converted my file to all tabs and the FlexBe App now recognizes the state as expected.

---

Originally posted by [chives_onion](https://answers.ros.org/users/39292/chives_onion/) with karma: 180 on 2020-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1